# Null pointer exception using CachedRowSetImpl

Tags: jsp, rowset

I'm trying to use CachedRowSetImpl, I add the rowset.jar but it gives an exception "Null pointer exception using CachedRowSetImpl" , any suggestions ?

Comment: Solved, follow this http://dagonsoftware.blogspot.com/2008/05/comsunrowsetcachedrowset-pains.html

Comment: Please add the steps to solve your problem (not just a link to the solution), add it as an answer an accept it!